# Importing modules from a folder

Tags: python

Im trying to add some libraries within my app to make it more portable.
The problem is that the app is built with not this in mind.

So to be more specific I want to have a folder in my package called libs and keep a copy of the libs used in my app there.

For example lets say I use MySQLdb library. In my app I am importing it like this

```
import mysqldb
```

I want to be able to use the same code but having mysqldb inside libs folder.

Is that possible? I tried some things with `__init__.py` but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just play around with sys.path and should achieve what you want. Just do at the beginning of your program:

```
import sys
sys.path = [$'path_to_your_lib_folder_here'$] + sys.path
```

This is not a best practice however and you need to be carefull especially if your software will be used as a third-party by other libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be putting MySQLdb anywhere inside your project. It's a third-party library, it should either be installed as a system package or inside your project's virtualenv.

Comment: True but what if I have to deploy the app on a server where I don't have the privileges to install things?

Comment: That's what a virtualenv is for.